# C++ Split namespace declarations

Tags: c++, namespaces

I was wondering wether namespaces can be splitted or if a definition of a namespace has to be in a single block. To illustrate what I mean:

```
namespace test
{
    //declare a bunch of stuff here
    int a;
}
```

Here we do something else like declaring a class or whatever

```
class T
{
};
```

and here continues the namespace from above, extending it

```
namespace test
{
    //declare a bunch of additional stuff here
    int b;
    T val;
}
```

In this example the namespace `test` has been used twice, so does this mean that `test` is extended by the second defintion? When I used it like this in gcc it works as expected. I can access all variables with `test::...` as if it were defined in a single namespace. Of course this doesn't make it standard, so I would like to know if this is according to the standard.

I was also surprised that I didn't even get a warning or such. But wouldn't this mean that you can accidently use a name which is already used without begin aware of it thus extending it?

Comment: No answer, because I can't quote the standard, but I always believed that this was the way to work with namespaces.  Why are you afraid of extending namespaces accidentally? If you don't use a separate namespace, you are extending the global namespace.

Comment: I always thought that i.e. `std::` should stay clean. I didn't know that it can be extended by anybody. In the example of `std` it might be confusing, but I can see that this is usefull in other cases, as I had to use this myself.

Comment: @Devolus Namespaces in general can be extended, but `std` is special and should _indeed_ stay clean, so _we_ are **not** allowed to extend it. I think the only kind of "addition" allowed for this namespace is specializing templates (notably `std::swap`) for your user-defined types (and specialization actually does not add new symbols).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly do that, an example is presented in C++11 standard N3485 Section 7.3.3.11

Quoted below.

> The entity declared by a using-declaration shall be known in the
>   context using it according to its definition at the point of the
>   using-declaration. Definitions added to the namespace after the
>   using-declaration are not considered when a use of the name is made.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace A 
> { 
>     void f(int); 
> } 
> using A::f; // f is a synonym for A::f; 
>             // that is, for A::f(int). 
> namespace A 
> { 
>     void f(char); 
> }
>
> void foo() 
> { 
>    f(’a’); // calls f(int), 
> }         // even though f(char) exists.
>
> void bar() 
> { 
>     sing A::f; // f is a synonym for A::f; 
>                // that is, for A::f(int) and A::f(char). 
>     f(’a’); // calls f(char) 
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can split the contents of a namespace over several sections.

If you compile using `gcc` and use `-ansi` and `-pedantic` will give you warnings for non-standard code.

A typical use-case of this is of course when you declared a set of things in a header file, and then implement these in a source file.

```
// header.h

namespace somename
{
   class A
   {
      // stuff goes here 
      void func();
      // more stuff. 
   }
 }
```

---

```
// source.cpp

#include "header.h"

namespace somename
{

   void A::func()
   {
      // whatever A::func() is supposed to do goes here. 
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using pedantic and wall, but that doesn't guaruantee that it is indeed standard. :)

Comment: If you use `-ansi`, the compiler should remove all extensions. Combining that with -pedantic will cause the compile to fail, as far as I can tell:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html